# Serving Django site over HTTPS

Tags: python, django, ssl, https

I have built a website in Django but I would like to serve it "as HTTPS" (encrypted over port 443).

I already have a certificate, but how do I configure Django to use it? Could it really be Django doesn't support this out of the box and if so how should I go about serving the site as HTTPS?

Server is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django. You must configure your web server to serve over HTTPS.

Comment: Yes w Selcuk.  Don't confuse Django's convenient dev server with a production intended web server.  nginx for example would do the trick just fine and there are a number of guides about https.  An apparently valid reason for wanting to have https on dev might be to match prod more closely.  However nginx-django https, while simple, is just different enough, while also transparent, not to make the bother worthwhile, IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not related to Django but it actually being supported. so follow this steps :

**1. Getting A Certificate**
use [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) because it's free!

**2. Updating Repositories And Installing Tools**
enter this command in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

if you don't have git already, install it by this command :

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

**3. Settings,**

1. change directory to your django project directory with `cd`

   ```
   cd django_project
   ```
2. run these commands :

   ```
   git clone https //github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
   ```

   then

   ```
   cd letsencrypt

   ./letsencrypt-auto --help
   ```

if you are here, it means everything works fine! so go to the next steps :

```
service nginx stop
```

(if you use another web servers try to stop them)

replace example.com with your domain name:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/django
```

edit the file like this :

```
server {
#listen 80 default_server;
#listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
```

and

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

now just restart the server.

Comment: @Stuffe if my answer was useful, please check it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Actually I already have a certificate as stated (letsencrypt). I didn't have nginx installed on my server, but looking into what it is right now.

Comment: Ok, you get the tick, it wasn't too hard to figure out after looking into nginx :)